# How to Split String at "," with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

String:

```
"ab, ac, Convert(ab,ac), test"
```

I want this stringArray:

```
ab
ac
Convert(ab,ac)
test
```

Comment: Note that if you need to take into consideration things like parentheses, then a regular grammar like regex won't be enough and you'll need to use something more complex. Either that or escape any characters you don't want to split by.

Answer (score 1):

```
,\s*(?![^(]*\))
```

Try this.Replace by `\n`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/28

This will work on inputs like `ab, ac, Convert(ab,ac),test,bc,mc,` too

Answer (score 0):

Just split your input acccording to `,\s+` or `, +` regexes. `\s+` matches one or more space characters.

```
string value = "ab, ac, Convert(ab,ac), test";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @", +");
foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Output:

```
ab
ac
Convert(ab,ac)
test
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/APzqJ0)